# django templates disappearing on refresh

Tags: python, html, django, list, loops

I have constructed a news aggregator website which shows 10 headlines with corresponding images, scraped from https://thestar.com ( The Toronto Star ) , using bs4.

Here's a photo for reference:
[image]

However, the major problem is, Everytime i refresh the page, all of the elements dissapear, As seen in the photo below :

[image]

Anyone know what the problem is?

Here is the element where my variables are stored:

```
<div class="col-6">
            <center><i><u><h3 class="text-centre">Live News from The Toronto Star</h3></u></i></center>
            {% for n, i in toronto %}
            <img src="{{i}}">
            <strong><h5>{{n}}</h5></strong>
            <hr>
            {% endfor %}
            <br>
        </div>
```

and here's my `views.py` file :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import re
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import itertools

# Getting news from The Toronto Star

toi_r = requests.get("https://www.thestar.com/?redirect=true")
toi_soup = BeautifulSoup(toi_r.content, 'html.parser')

toi_headings = toi_soup.find_all('h3')

toi_headings = toi_headings[0:10]# removing footers

toi_news = []

for th in toi_headings:
    toi_news.append(th.text)


#Getting news from the NY Times

ht_r = requests.get("https://www.nytimes.com/")
ht_soup = BeautifulSoup(ht_r.content, 'html.parser')
ht_headings = ht_soup.findAll('h3')
ht_headings = ht_headings[0:8] + ht_headings[10:12] + ht_headings[19:21]
ht_news = []

for hth in ht_headings:
    ht_news.append(hth.text)

# Getting Images from The Toronto Star

tor_r = requests.get("https://www.thestar.com/")
data = re.search(r"window\.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = (.*)", tor_r.text)
data = json.loads(data.group(1))

def find_images(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            if k == "image":
                yield v
            else:
                yield from find_images(v)
    if isinstance(d, list):
        for v in d:
            yield from find_images(v)

images = []

for img in find_images(data):
    if img["url"]:
        images.append("https://www.thestar.com" + img["url"])

images = images[4:14]

#zip file to concurrently loop news and headlines in the django templates inside my index.html file

toronto = zip(toi_news, images)

def index(req):
    return render(req, 'news/index.html', {'toi_news':toi_news, 'ht_news': ht_news, 'images': images, 'toronto': toronto})
```

Comment: Place the code that make requests to API and creates context object inside the index view function and try. If that doesn't resolve your issue, please post your urls.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, found the solution myself. I just had to add a `list()` function around the `zip()` function in the `toronto` variable on line 79 of my `views.py` file. Hope this helped someone out!